# How to position a div that already has a float?

Tags: html, css

I have a set of divs that I have set to float:left and I am wanting them to all be in line with each other but still be centered, this is what I currently have:

HTML

```
<div style="display: inline; text-align:center;">
    <div id="generalmenu">
        test
    </div>
    <div id="generalmenu">
        test
    </div>
    <div id="generalmenu">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#phonicmenu { 
    background: white; 
}
#generalmenu { 
    background: white; 
    width:270; 
    padding: 25px; 
    float:left; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
}
```

Any idea on how I can center these menus?

EDIT:
Added a JS Fiddle with a body so you can see the problem clearer.
http://jsfiddle.net/aYWwM/

Comment: What exactly does not work? what are you expecting?

Comment: float:center; does not exist..

Comment: I'm expecting the divs to be centered next to each other, the wrapper doesn't seem to be centering them.

Comment: First of all, make `generalmenu` a **class**. Only one element can have a specific **id**. Also can you make a jsfiddle for us?

Comment: perhaps this may help: http://pmob.co.uk/pob/centred-float.htm

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's an id and not a class, it'll work the same. http://jsfiddle.net/aYWwM/ is my JSFiddle

Comment: I'm not entirely interested in using lists.

Comment: You can't 'float:left' and 'text-align: center'. The CSS will conflict. That's the equivalent of saying you're standing in the left side of the room and in the center of the room at the same time. If you float the items left, you can add a 'margin-left' to the first item to manually center the divs. One thing to note. If you know where you want each container to be you can absolute position them relative to the parent container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is also that you are using `div`s for purposes they aren't made for. A div is a block element. You want to display stuff as inline elements, so you should use `span` or an unordered list.

To do what you need, simply create a wrapping div and have its `margin-left` and `margin-right` set to `auto`. The wrapper should contain inline elements of what you need... See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4eJsF/)

Comment: You could also set "display: inline-block;" for the divs, as you some times can not change the element type.

Comment: I'm not using them for the wrong reason, I am going to be inserting forms and images at a later stage, I just want to perfect the positioning first.

Comment: Please see my jsfiddle and decide if it is what you need. You can use `divs`if you have to, and change `display` to `inline` or `inline-block`.

Comment: @Matthew Also, if you're planning to create some custom extensive menu, someone probably already has made something as there are literally thousands of free menus available on the internet...